# Prove the inequalities $Q(p)\sqrt{\frac{p}{n}}\le Q(n)\le Q(p)\sqrt{\frac{2p+1}{2n+1}}$

Tags: inequality

Let $Q(n)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{4}...\frac{2n-1}{2n}$

For $n\ge p, p\in N$ prove that

$Q(p)\sqrt{\frac{p}{n}}\le Q(n)\le Q(p)\sqrt{\frac{2p+1}{2n+1}}$

I started with $Q(n)=Q(p)\frac{2p+1}{2p+2}...\frac{2n-1}{2n}$ and maybe I have to complete it
with inequalities ($\frac{x}{y} \lt \frac{x+p}{y+p}$) to get some expression involving Q(n) and Q(p) squared and $\frac{p}{n}$. How could I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first equation we use $Q(n)=Q(p)\frac{2p+1}{2p+2}...\frac{2n-1}{2n}$ and take the square. Then we get 
$$Q(p)\sqrt{\frac{p}{n}}\le Q(n)\iff 2p(2p+2)^2\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n)^2\leq 2n (2p+1)^2\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n-1)^2.$$
Rearranging the left side we get 
$$2p(2p+2)^2\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n)^2= \\
[2p(2p+2)]\cdot\ldots\cdot[(2n-2)2n]\cdot 2n= \\
[(2p+1)^2-1)]\cdot\ldots\cdot[(2n-1)^2-1]\cdot 2n$$
Comparing the factors gives the desired inequality. A similar calculation should prove the second inequality.

Comment: That's right. Only a small typing mistake [(2n−1)^2-1] instead [(2n−1)^2+1].

Comment: You're right. I've changed it.